# Numpy divide on ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to create a new array containing the ratios of another ndarray.

**First simple example:**

```
import numpy as np
week = np.full((3, 4), 2, dtype=float)
week[:,2] = 0
week[2,0:2] =0
week[0,3] =0.99
week[1,3] =1.99
week[2,3] =0.89

week
```

returns

```
array([[2.  , 2.  , 0.  , 0.99],
       [2.  , 2.  , 0.  , 1.99],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.89]])
```

Now I want to calculate a ndarray containing the ratios of week[:,3]

```
ratio =  week[:,3].reshape(1,-1).T/ week[:,3]
```

returns

```
array([[1.   , 0.497, 1.112],
       [2.01 , 1.   , 2.236],
       [0.899, 0.447, 1.   ]])
```

exactly what I want.

**More general case**
A 5d array where the first 4 dimensions can change

```
weeks_5d= np.full((1,1,2, 3, 4), 2, dtype=float)
weeks_5d[:,:,:,:,2] = 0
weeks_5d[:,:,0,2,0:2] =0
weeks_5d[:,:,1,1,0:2] =0
weeks_5d[:,:,:,0,3] = 0.99
weeks_5d[:,:,:,1,3] = 1.99
weeks_5d[:,:,:,2,3] = 0.89

weeks_5d
```

returns

```
array([[[[[2.  , 2.  , 0.  , 0.99],
          [2.  , 2.  , 0.  , 1.99],
          [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.89]],

         [[2.  , 2.  , 0.  , 0.99],
          [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.99],
          [2.  , 2.  , 0.  , 0.89]]]]])
```

Now I want to calculate the same ratio for each ndarray

Transposing the 5darray returns weird results.

What I need is

```
   array([[[[[1.   , 0.497, 1.112],
              [2.01 , 1.   , 2.236],
              [0.899, 0.447, 1.   ]]],

             [[1.   , 0.497, 1.112],
              [2.01 , 1.   , 2.236],
              [0.899, 0.447, 1.   ]]]]])
```

Comment: do you need to do this for 5d arrays, or in general for any shape of array?

Comment: the reason I ask is it might be impossible to do what you are looking to do with simple simply numpy broadcasting rules.  In such a case you may have to create a new array and loop over it performing the basic operation and populating the new array with results, which is simple to conceive of doing on a fixed set of dimensions but a little more challenging on a variable set of dimensions

Comment: This would be always for a 5d array. I also thought about do a loop and stack arrays, but might be a bottleneck performance wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a loop is your best hope here and there is a slow and a fast way to do it:

### the slow way:

```
def get_ratios(arr):
    ni, nj, nk = arr.shape[:3]
    last_dim = arr.shape[3]

    new_arr = np.zeros(shape=(ni, nj, nk, last_dim, last_dim),
                       dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(ni):
        for j in range(nj):
            for k in range(nk):
                week = arr[i, j, k]
                ratio = week[:, 3].reshape(-1, 1) / week[:, 3]
                new_arr[i, j, k] = ratio

    return new_arr

get_ratios(weeks_5d)
```

prints

```
array([[[[[1.        , 0.49748744, 1.11235955],
          [2.01010101, 1.        , 2.23595506],
          [0.8989899 , 0.44723618, 1.        ]],

         [[1.        , 0.49748744, 1.11235955],
          [2.01010101, 1.        , 2.23595506],
          [0.8989899 , 0.44723618, 1.        ]]]]])
```

Obviously looping over arrays in python is slow but that's what `numba` was invented for:

### the fast(er) way

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def get_ratios(arr):
    ni, nj, nk = arr.shape[:3]
    last_dim = arr.shape[3]

    new_arr = np.zeros(shape=(ni, nj, nk, last_dim, last_dim),
                       dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(ni):
        for j in range(nj):
            for k in range(nk):
                week = arr[i, j, k, :, 3]
                for d1 in range(last_dim):
                    for d2 in range(last_dim):
                        new_arr[i, j, k, d1, d2] = week[d1] / week[d2]

    return new_arr

get_ratios(weeks_5d)
```

prints

```
array([[[[[1.        , 0.49748744, 1.11235955],
          [2.01010101, 1.        , 2.23595506],
          [0.8989899 , 0.44723618, 1.        ]],

         [[1.        , 0.49748744, 1.11235955],
          [2.01010101, 1.        , 2.23595506],
          [0.8989899 , 0.44723618, 1.        ]]]]])
```

Comment: Thx a lot, never heard about numba . What a great packages. I am using a ton of loops + numpy arrays in my code.

If i time i go from 23 µs to 1.5µs using numba

Comment: Its a favorite package of mine for exactly these kinds of reasons

Comment: There are two things to further speed up this function. 1) You overwrite every value in new_arr, so you can allocate a empty array instead. (`np.zeros` is equivalent to `np.empty`  + ndim nested loops to fill the array with zeros) 2) You are cheking for a division by 0 on every division which is the Python standard behaviour and can be quite costly. You can avoid this by setting `@njit(error_model="numpy")`

Comment: sweet, although I knew about the empty (just didn't think about it), did not know about the error model.  Thanks for the tip